# swiftui+combine: why isFavoriteO changed when scroll the LazyVGrid?

Tags: swiftui, combine

I have a LazyVGrid, every item with is favorite button. and use combine to debounce user input($isFavoriteI), when isFavoriteO changed, then modify the items.

it works fine, but when i scroll the list, log will print: "X, isFavorite changed as false/true)", what cause isFavoriteO changed and why? because of item reusing in list? how to avoid it?

```
index 7, isFavorite changed as true
index 7, isFavorite changed as true
index 7, isFavorite changed as true
index 7, isFavorite changed as true
index 7, isFavorite changed as true
index 7, isFavorite changed as true
index 7, isFavorite changed as true
index 7, isFavorite changed as true
```

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct Item {
    var index: Int
    var favorite: Bool
}

var items = [
    Item(index: 0, favorite: true),
    Item(index: 1, favorite: false),
    Item(index: 2, favorite: true),
    Item(index: 3, favorite: false),
    Item(index: 4, favorite: true),
    Item(index: 5, favorite: false),
    Item(index: 6, favorite: true),
    Item(index: 7, favorite: false),
//    Item(index: 8, favorite: true),
//    Item(index: 9, favorite: false),
//    Item(index: 10, favorite: true),
//    Item(index: 11, favorite: false),
//    Item(index: 12, favorite: true),
//    Item(index: 13, favorite: false),
//    Item(index: 14, favorite: true),
//    Item(index: 15, favorite: false),
//    Item(index: 16, favorite: true),
//    Item(index: 17, favorite: false),
//    Item(index: 18, favorite: true),
//    Item(index: 19, favorite: false),
]

struct ViewModelInListTestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
            LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 200), spacing: 4, alignment: .center)], spacing: 4) {
                ForEach(items, id: \.index) { item in
                    ItemView(item: item)
                }
            }
        }.navigationTitle("ViewModel In List")
    }
}

struct ItemView: View {
    let item: Item
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    init(item: Item) {
        print("ItemView.init, \(item.index)")
        self.item = item
        self.viewModel = ViewModel(item: item)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("index \(item.index)")
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: viewModel.isFavoriteI ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
                .foregroundColor(viewModel.isFavoriteI ? .red : .white)
                .padding()
                .onTapGesture { onFavoriteTapped() }
                .onChange(of: viewModel.isFavoriteO) { isFavorite in
                    setFavorite(isFavorite)
                }
        }
        .frame(width: 200, height: 150)
        .background(Color.gray)
    }
    
    func onFavoriteTapped() {
        viewModel.isFavoriteI.toggle()
    }
    
    func setFavorite(_ isFavorite: Bool) {
        print("index \(item.index), isFavorite changed as \(isFavorite)")
        items[item.index].favorite = isFavorite
    }
    
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var isFavoriteI: Bool = false
        @Published var isFavoriteO: Bool = false
        private var subscriptions: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
        
        init(item: Item) {
            print("ViewModel.init, \(item.index)")
            let isFavorite = item.favorite
            isFavoriteI = isFavorite; isFavoriteO = isFavorite
            $isFavoriteI
                .print("index \(item.index) isFavoriteI:")
                .dropFirst()
                .debounce(for: .milliseconds(500), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
                .removeDuplicates()
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
                .print("index \(item.index) isFavoriteO:")
                .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
                .assign(to: \.isFavoriteO, on: self)
                .store(in: &subscriptions)
        }
    }
}
```

update @ 4.15
according to @Cenk Bilgen, i re-write the code, but strange thing happened. print("set favorite as (favorite)") will not present if adding removeDuplicates. why?

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct Item: Identifiable {
    var index: Int
    var favorite: Bool
    var id: Int { index }
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [
        Item(index: 0, favorite: true),
        Item(index: 1, favorite: false),
        Item(index: 2, favorite: true),
        Item(index: 3, favorite: false),
        Item(index: 4, favorite: true),
        Item(index: 5, favorite: false),
        Item(index: 6, favorite: true),
        Item(index: 7, favorite: false),
    ]
}

struct ViewModelInListTestView: View {
    @StateObject var model = Model()
    var body: some View {
        print("ViewModelInListTestView refreshing"); return
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
            LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 200), spacing: 4, alignment: .center)], spacing: 4) {
                ForEach(model.items.indices) { index in
                    ItemView(item: model.items[index])
                        .environmentObject(model)
                }
            }
        }.navigationTitle("ViewModel In List")
    }
    
    
    struct ItemView: View {
        @EnvironmentObject var model: Model
        let item: Item
        @State private var updateFavourite = PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never>()
        @State private var favorite: Bool = false
        
        init(item: Item) {
            self.item = item
            self._favorite = State(initialValue: item.favorite)
        }
        
        var body: some View {
            print("ItemView \(item.index) refreshing"); return
            HStack {
                Text("index \(item.index)")
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: favorite ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
                    .foregroundColor(favorite ? .red : .white)
                    .padding()
                    .onTapGesture {
                        favorite.toggle()
                        updateFavourite.send(favorite)
                    }
                    .onReceive(
                        updateFavourite
                            .debounce(for: .seconds(0.5), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
//                            .removeDuplicates()  <------ HERE
//                            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
                    ) { favorite in
                        print("set favorite as \(favorite)")
                        model.items[item.index].favorite = favorite
                    }
            }
            .frame(width: 200, height: 150)
            .background(Color.gray)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You are recreating your viewModel every time an ItemView is initialized (which is often, every time it is redrawn). I think you may be able to remove it altogether and clarify the code by changing the `.onTapGesture` handler to be a publisher with the debounce logic in there.

Comment: `ItemView.init, 7
ViewModel.init, 7
index 7 isFavoriteO:: receive subscription: (RemoveDuplicates)
index 7 isFavoriteO:: request unlimited
index 7 isFavoriteI:: receive subscription: (PublishedSubject)
index 7 isFavoriteI:: request unlimited
index 7 isFavoriteI:: receive value: (false)
index 0, isFavorite changed as false
index 7, isFavorite changed as true` according to this log, viewmodel never initialized evert time re-draw the ItemView.

Comment: Looking at the code, you are calling `self.viewModel = ViewModel(item: item)` in the third line of the View's initializer and that initializer is called whenever the view needs to be redrawn (in the case of SwiftUI redrawn means the struct is recreated). My suggestion would be to initialize it outside init, for example make it a @StateObject or alternatively I think you can refactor to move the responsibility of debouncing the tap in the tap gesture itself.

Comment: You can try run my code, trace the log. It's not easy. I think even apple issue here.

Comment: You're right, it's not easy. I've added an answer below, which is not great and I'm not sure is exactly the behaviour you want with debounce, but might help.

Comment: Try putting the remove duplicates before the debounce, so it will drop consecutive trues/falses before even dealing with the debounce timer. But really removeDuplicates shouldn't be necessary, because by the time a value reaches the `sink` closure without being dropped earlier, you have two options. 1. toggle the published value; or 2. ignore the published value and toggle the current value in the model. I would do the second because what the publisher is publishing might have changed by then.

Comment: it's unreasonable putting the remove duplicates before the debounce, because no any duplicates there, must be true\false\true\false. but after the debounce, duplicates exist. anyway, have no idea about this issue. i think favorite.toggle() cause it, this toggle recreate view, and effect the updateFavourite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
  var index: Int
  var favorite: Bool
  var id: Int { index }
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
  @Published var items = [
    Item(index: 0, favorite: true),
    Item(index: 1, favorite: false),
    Item(index: 2, favorite: true),
    Item(index: 3, favorite: false),
    Item(index: 4, favorite: true),
    Item(index: 5, favorite: false),
    Item(index: 6, favorite: true),
    Item(index: 7, favorite: false),
    ]
}

struct SimplerView: View {
  @StateObject var model = Model()
  var body: some View {
    ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
      LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 200), spacing: 4, alignment: .center)], spacing: 4) {
        ForEach(items.indices) { index in
          ItemView(item: $model.items[index])
            .environmentObject(model)
        }
      }
    }.navigationTitle("ViewModel In List")
  }
  
  
  struct ItemView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model
    @Binding var item: Item
    @State private var updateFavourite = PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never>()
    
    var body: some View {
      HStack {
        Text("index \(item.index)")
        Spacer()
        Image(systemName: item.favorite ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
          .foregroundColor(item.favorite ? .red : .white)
          .padding()
          .onTapGesture {
            updateFavourite.send(item.favorite)
          }
          .onReceive(updateFavourite
                      .debounce(for: .seconds(0.5), scheduler: RunLoop.main)) { value in
                        item.favorite = !value
          }
        }
      .frame(width: 200, height: 150)
      .background(Color.gray)
    }
  }
  
}
```

Comment: strange thing: cannot got response if add removeDuplicates like following: `.onReceive(updateFavourite.debounce(for: .seconds(0.5), scheduler: RunLoop.main).removeDuplicates())`

Comment: you will found "receive cancel" instead of "receive value: (false)" when add print after debounce.

Comment: pls see my updated code at the end of original post, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand how isFavoriteI and isFavoriteO work, but you
could try this:

in ItemView remove the

```
.onChange(of: viewModel.isFavoriteO) { isFavorite in
   setFavorite(isFavorite)
}
```

and change:

```
func onFavoriteTapped() {
    viewModel.isFavoriteI.toggle()
    print("\(item.index), isFavorite changed as \(viewModel.isFavoriteI)")
    items[item.index].favorite = viewModel.isFavoriteI
}
```

Comment: isFavoriteI(nput) and isFavoriteO(utput) in viewModel are for debouncing user input. when i tap the favorite button multiple time quickly, isFavoriteI will updated every time, but isFavoriteO only updated at last tapping.

Comment: I'm sure cell reusable causes this issue. LazyVGrid & LazyVStack will lead to this, but VStack not. I think when ItemView is reused, that means another Item data set to the old same ItemView. this produce does not fire ItemView init()(print("ItemView.init, \(item.index)") not present) or $isFavoriteI(print("index \(item.index) isFavoriteI:") not present), but fires .onChange(of: viewModel.isFavoriteO)(print("index \(item.index), isFavorite changed as \(isFavorite)") present). it's wired, how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

The best of doing this is in this way in down code, SwiftUI would stop unnecessary render, and it will render if it needs!

You had some issue that you should use id for your items, plus combine does not work well in this case, so use better and easier way in down:

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var itemModel: ItemModel = sharedItemModel
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView {
            
            LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 200), spacing: 4, alignment: .center)], spacing: 4) {
                
                ForEach(Array(itemModel.items.enumerated()), id:\.element.id) { (offset, element) in
                    
                    ItemView(index: offset, favorite: element.favorite)
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
        Button("append new random element") { itemModel.items.append(Item(favorite: Bool.random())) }
        .padding()
        
        
    }
}
```

---

```
struct ItemView: View {
    
    let index: Int
    let favorite: Bool
    
    init(index: Int, favorite: Bool) {
        self.index = index
        self.favorite = favorite
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        print("rendering item: " + index.description)
        
        return HStack {
            
            Text("index " + index.description)
                .bold()
                .padding()

            Spacer()
            
            Image(systemName: favorite ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                .padding()
                .onTapGesture { sharedItemModel.items[index].favorite.toggle() }

        }
        .frame(width: 200, height: 150)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .cornerRadius(10.0)
    }
    
}
```

---

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    var favorite: Bool
    
}

class ItemModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var items: [Item] = [Item]()
    
}

let sharedItemModel: ItemModel = ItemModel()
```

---

Comment: 1. ForEach(items, id: \.index), id used. 2. combine does not work? it's just in wrong way i think. combine is needed for debouncing user input. 3. your code can not solve my problem.

Comment: You just misunderstood my words! That meant to say using combine for solving your issue is not a right move! But we can have different believes, no problem

Comment: what can i do to debounce user input without combine? any suggestion?